# HTTP content length exceeded 4194304 bytes

Tags: little-proxy

While testing I observed that media attachments more than 4194304 bytes are rejected by the proxy. It throws the message - "HTTP content length exceeded 4194304 bytes".

Is this the functionality of LittleProxy implementation or there is any configuration which will allow bigger size of attachments than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a `TooLongFrameException` thrown by [`HttpObjectAggregator`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/70e7bcc963f180aa0f88fdaa415fd8ba1025cd60/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObjectAggregator.java#L174).

The only way that I think this could happen is when using an [`HttpFiltersSource`](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/littleshoot/proxy/HttpFiltersSource.java) that specifies a non-zero value from `getMaximumRequestBufferSizeInBytes()` or `getMaximumResponseBufferSizeInBytes()`.  You can increase those, but that increases your memory usage.  If the filter can be rewritten so as to work with frames (chunks) as they stream through, then you can set the buffer size to 0 and dramatically reduce your memory consumption.

Comment: I found the code in my application which was setting this limit. However I did not quite get one thing, how the filter can work at the frame (or chunk) level by itself. If I understood it correct, it is upto the content server, which serves the content, decides how to serve it. The filter is running at the Proxy sitting in between. In case of progressive download video, the content typically comes as a blob. AFA video streaming is concerned, at TCP level GoP boundaries are not guaranteed. In case of adaptive streaming, the content server (eg Youtube) itself serves the content in chunked form.