# Netty IO HttpObjectAggregator fails to work with large transfer files

Tags: netty

I am new with Netty IO.  I used HttpObjectAggregator() and is working great . However, I just got a requirement to do file transfer of large sizes. I have set the Aggregator CTOR value to very large number and as expected got Out of Memory Errors. If I don't then I get TooLongFrameException. 
Is there a way, that I can still use the HttpObjectAggregator and somehow by pass this issue? And if not what else can I do?

Note that I am working inside of a Proxy similar to a Load Balancer.
 Cheers,
John

Comment: Did you consider this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407414/http-content-length-exceeded-4194304-bytes/20424128#20424128 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just finished looking at it... honestly not sure if I understand it. Maybe you can share some high level view of this solution.

Comment: From Netty's documentation A ChannelHandler that adds support for writing a large data stream asynchronously neither spending a lot of memory nor getting OutOfMemoryError. Large data streaming such as file transfer requires complicated state management in a ChannelHandler implementation. ChunkedWriteHandler manages such complicated states so that you can send a large data stream without difficulties. checkout another example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357672/sending-file-from-server-to-client-by-using-netty-io

Comment: Thanks for the help... My addition issue is that I am trying to implement a Proxy like a simple Load Balancer; thus I believe I cant use this File approach.